# Passing data to next Activity using Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

JSONObject data has the received firebase notification messages.Notifications are stacked on tray. If i click the notification that particular message should be passed on to next activity.First value of message is "Hi" and Second value of message is "Hello". I should have to send both values to next activity. But only "Hello"(Second Value) is printing in the next activity

```
 private void sendPushNotification(JSONObject json) {
    //optionally we can display the json into log
    Log.e(TAG, "Notification JSON " + json.toString());
    try {
        //getting the json data
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

        //parsing json data
        String title = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("message");
        String imageUrl = data.getString("image");

        //creating MyNotificationManager object
        MyNotificationManager mNotificationManager = new MyNotificationManager(getApplicationContext());


        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("time",message);
        //if there is no image
        if(imageUrl.equals("null")){
            //displaying small notification
            mNotificationManager.showSmallNotification(title, message, intent);
        }else{
            //if there is an image
            //displaying a big notification
            mNotificationManager.showBigNotification(title, message, imageUrl, intent);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

HomeActivity.java

```
  Intent i=getIntent();
  String times = i.getStringExtra("time");
```

Comment: can u share the full code, how you are setting the value, and how are you retrieving it.

Comment: You use same key for both strings, so only second is saved.

Comment: Try the answer I gave.

Answer (score 0):

```
// In Current Activity
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key_hi", "Hi");
bundle.putString("key_hello", "Hello");

Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);

// In HomeActivity.java
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String strHi = bundle.getString("key_hi");
String strHello = bundle.getString("key_hello");
```

Comment: @Shekar Actually Json message contains only the last received notification's message and it is getting passed to next activity

Comment: so, do you want to save the previous notification also.

Comment: @Shekar My exact need is on tapping any notification from multiple received notifications in notification bar , only that message should be passed to next activity